# PNG Image not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using a bootstrap collapsed navigation for when my site is viewed on a mobile. I want to hide my logo from the top of the page and put it inline with my toggle button to save some screen space. When I try to place my image into the navbar it doesn't seem to display, all that displays is my ALT text. Here is the code i'm currently using.

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav  id="menu1"  class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                     <div id="logo" class="pull-left hidden-md hidden-lg">
                            <div class="img-responsive logo-small">
                                <img src="images/logo-xs.png" alt="small-logo"/>
                         </div>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
                                        'depth' => 2,
                                          'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                                         'menu_class' => 'nav nav-pills nav-justified',
                                        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker() )); ?>

            </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: When your alt tag is showing, but the image is not, this could mean that your path/image name is wrong.

Comment: First of all, have you specified the correct image path? Can you right click the location where the image should be and view it in your browsers debugger (Inspect element in chrome..), try opening the image by right clicking the url in the element viewer and select "open in new tab", you could also use the resource viewer to see if the image have been loaded correctly) (while this might not be the problem, it is fairly quick to try)

Comment: I use brackets and when I hover over the link path it shows me the image that I want to display, so I'm pretty certain the image path is correct, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find the network request for the image using Chrome Dev Tools for instance.

[Chrome Dev Tools, network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing a closing `</div>` tag. I suppose it should be just before the `<button>`

Comment: Sorry I just didn't put it in, it goes after my final div to close the row. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a closing "div" tag. Because between "nav" tag section open three "div" but close two "div" tag.